# How to edit EXIF data of mp4 video file in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, xaml, video, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

Is anybody know how possible to edit EXIF data of video file in Windows Phone 8.1?

Case i can record video (screen capture) and need to modify EXIF data of video.
Example:

```
StorageFolder folder = KnownFolders.VideosLibrary;
string currentFileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yy-MM-dd__hh-mm-ss");
StorageFile videoFile = await folder.CreateFileAsync(currentFileName+".mp4", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

...

```
// Create an encoding profile to use.                  
var profile = Windows.Media.MediaProperties.MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp4(Windows.Media.MediaProperties.VideoEncodingQuality.HD1080p);
// Start recording
await _mediaCapture.StartRecordToStorageFileAsync(profile, videoFile);
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had a chance to test this myself to see where the metadata is written but the [StorageFolder.Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefile.properties.aspx) property might be what you are looking for.

```
StorageFile file = //get a file
Dictionary<String, object> propertiesToSave = new Dictionary<string, object>();

//This provides convenient access to the properties
var videoProps = await file.Properties.GetVideoPropertiesAsync();

//You can add as many properties to save as you want here
propertiesToSave.Add("System.Video.Director", "Director Name");

videoProps.SavePropertiesAsync(propertiesToSave);
```

[The list of properties is useful for finding what you can write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff384862%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Edit: Added more details for clarity on how to save properties.

Comment: Yes, i already try this one, for example:

`var items = await eyeFile.Properties.GetVideoPropertiesAsync();
 eyeFile.Properties.GetVideoPropertiesAsync();
 items.Publisher = "Hello world!";
 items.SavePropertiesAsync();`

This variant work's fine, but unfortunatly i cant add data to such property like 'MakerNote', and most of other properties (for example like longtitude, latitude is readonly)

P.S. MSDN page - http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileproperties.videoproperties